# How to use the ref with the react-hook-form react library?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to use the `react` `ref` with a simple form input defined with `react-hook-form` library like below (based on [the official docs](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/register)).

Here is the code excerpt I'm dealing with:

```
<input id="lastName" 
{ ...myRegister('lastName', { 
  required: true,
  onChange: (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
  },
  ref: (input) => { 
    console.log("lastName ref...")
    textInput2 = input
  }
  })
} />
```

The `onChange` handler function is working as expected (printing the input current value ) BUT the `ref` doesn't! - the string `lastName` ref... isn't printed nor `textInput2` initialized with the `input` variable!

What I'm doing wrong above!?

Can someone please give me an working example of the `ref` attribute defined with the `react-hook-form` library?

Comment: From the doc you sent, I see the `ref` is not of value type `ChangeHandler`  it needs `React.Ref<any>:  Input reference for hook form to register.` So create a react ref and provide it that.

Comment: @Sarthak Dwivedi Ok friend can You be so kind and give me an example?

Comment: sorry never used this library myself before, but just check at the end of the [register()](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/register/) doc you shared it does give an example already on `How to work with innerRef, inputRef?` <-- Titltle is the same. Also, the Register method sets default ref for you, the example should make things more clear.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The library uses a ref internally to keep track of the value. To add your own ref please check: https://www.react-hook-form.com/faqs/#Howtosharerefusage

```
import { useRef } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

export default function App() {
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();
  const firstNameRef = useRef(null);
  const onSubmit = data => console.log(data);
  const { ref, ...rest } = register('firstName');

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <input {...rest} name="firstName" ref={(e) => {
        ref(e)
        firstNameRef.current = e // you can still assign to ref
      }} />

      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Comment: Ok I think i got it. By doing `ref={(e) => {...}` I'm just extends the default, implicit in-library usage of the ref adding to it my own extras, But The question now arises: What would happen if in the above code I just comment out the `ref(e)` line disabling the internal library usage of the ref? I've done so fore experimental purposes and no errors , everything seems to work. So what would be the impact of omitting calling the default internal ref usage?

Comment: exactly my case. I searched through all the internet until I find this. Thank you

Comment: dammit I had to debug for half an hour only to realize the library is causing it